# The combined SEM of two averages with SEM

Tags: mean, error

I am looking to calculate the difference in blood flow between the controls and intervention group (dipyridamole) and whether this is significant.

The table 2 shows the average blood flow + SEM each from 20 measurements

To calculate this I am taking the average of the inner (In) and outer (Out) blood flow in each group - so you get 0.19 for the control and 0.145 for the intervention. But how do I get the standard error for these averages to see if the difference is significant?

It should be said that the authors reports a P=0,05 for the difference, but I cannot seem to arrive at this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is part of a table from: L. C. Becker, *Conditions for Vasodilator-induced Coronary Steal in Experimental Myocardial Ischemia*. Circulation 57: 1103-1110, 1978.

You will not be able to reproduce the results from the data provided, as these are the mean and SEM values *among all hearts* within each treatment condition, while the Methods section states (page 1105): "The statistical significance of differences in results was determined by Student's *t*-test for **paired** data." (Emphasis added.) That is, each heart served as its own control for purposes of the statistical test. Unless you have the paired data you cannot reproduce this analysis. This is often a problem in trying to reproduce results from published studies.

Also, the author performed separate tests for the "In" (inner) and "Out" (outer) layers of the ventricular wall  as, unlike in this excerpt, some other rows in this table show "significance stars" for both layers. The author only claimed here a significant difference related to drug treatment for the outer layer of the Ischemic region, not for the inner layer. (The claim in this case was "P <0.001 vs control.") You tried to combine the 2 layers for your comparison, which is not what the author did. As there seems to be a substantial difference in the response of blood flow to the drug combination depending on the ventricular wall layer examined (a significant interaction effect) you typically wouldn't want to average results for the 2 layers.